# Object comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, comparison, object-comparison

What is the best way to compare objects in JavaScript?

Example:

```
var user1 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
var user2 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
var eq = user1 == user2;
alert(eq); // gives false
```

I know that **two objects are equal if they refer to the exact same object**, but is there a way to check if they have the same attributes' values?

The following way works for me, but is it the only possibility?

```
var eq = Object.toJSON(user1) == Object.toJSON(user2);
alert(eq); // gives true
```

Comment: I tinkered a bit on the topic and devised a flexible solution to the problem http://stamat.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/javascript-object-comparison/

Comment: testing for (deep) equality is quite a difficult thing to get right. head over to https://github.com/loveencounterflow/jseq to see a test suite of popular `equal()` implementations that already covers many edge cases. the discussion in the docs is also quite thorough.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/yazjisuhail/js/blob/master/implementations/deepEqual.js) implementation might be helpful and/or effective.

Comment: I added an answer for it at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects/27014537#27014537

In fact, that has many good answers, even though this is the first search result.

Comment: Use lodash. It's `isEqual` method does exactly what you want.

Comment: use https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ and this operation will be super easy & fast

Comment: I found an easy way. `function equal (x,y){ return x >= y && x <= y}`

Comment: Even better: `function equal (x,y){ return !( x < y || x > y)}`. [It works properly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d0TXO.png) for objects, arrays, numbers, strings, NaN, and even functions. Warning: it will coerce types and methods will be ignored.

Comment: using underscore, `_.isEqual( obj1 , obj2 )`

Comment: You can install this via npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal

Comment: `VM304:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object.toJSON is not a function`

Comment: I think you can compare all things by just only

`function _isEqual(val, oval) {
    return (JSON.stringify({a: val}) === JSON.stringify({a: oval}))
}`

Comment: There is a more elegant solution here: https://kcak11.github.io/jslib/deepCompareObjects.js

This one is easier to understand and does the job !!

Comment: Here is the simple way to compare two object : var user1 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
var user2 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(user1).toString() === JSON.stringify(user2).toString()); // true

Comment: More information please refer : http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Comment: JSON.stringify may help you

Comment: https://jsben.ch/1uLAP <= performance comparison between JSON.stringify and fast-deep-equal

Comment: i want to know how good of an option is this.

Comment: function compareObjects(firstObj, secObj) {
        return Object.entries(firstObj).every(([k ,v]) =>  
            typeof v === "object" ? 
            compareObjects(v, secObj[k]) :
            v === secObj[k]
        )
    }

Answer (score 1775, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no perfect way, unless you use `_proto_` recursively and access all non-enumerable properties, but this works in Firefox only.

So the best I can do is to guess usage scenarios.

---

### **1) Fast and limited.**

Works when you have simple JSON-style objects without methods and DOM nodes inside:

```
 JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

The ORDER of the properties IS IMPORTANT, so this method will return false for following objects:

```
 x = {a: 1, b: 2};
 y = {b: 2, a: 1};
```

---

### **2) Slow and more generic.**

Compares objects without digging into prototypes, then compares properties' projections recursively, and also compares constructors.

This is almost correct algorithm:

```
function deepCompare () {
  var i, l, leftChain, rightChain;

  function compare2Objects (x, y) {
    var p;

    // remember that NaN === NaN returns false
    // and isNaN(undefined) returns true
    if (isNaN(x) && isNaN(y) && typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') {
         return true;
    }

    // Compare primitives and functions.     
    // Check if both arguments link to the same object.
    // Especially useful on the step where we compare prototypes
    if (x === y) {
        return true;
    }

    // Works in case when functions are created in constructor.
    // Comparing dates is a common scenario. Another built-ins?
    // We can even handle functions passed across iframes
    if ((typeof x === 'function' && typeof y === 'function') ||
       (x instanceof Date && y instanceof Date) ||
       (x instanceof RegExp && y instanceof RegExp) ||
       (x instanceof String && y instanceof String) ||
       (x instanceof Number && y instanceof Number)) {
        return x.toString() === y.toString();
    }

    // At last checking prototypes as good as we can
    if (!(x instanceof Object && y instanceof Object)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (x.isPrototypeOf(y) || y.isPrototypeOf(x)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (x.constructor !== y.constructor) {
        return false;
    }

    if (x.prototype !== y.prototype) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for infinitive linking loops
    if (leftChain.indexOf(x) > -1 || rightChain.indexOf(y) > -1) {
         return false;
    }

    // Quick checking of one object being a subset of another.
    // todo: cache the structure of arguments[0] for performance
    for (p in y) {
        if (y.hasOwnProperty(p) !== x.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (typeof y[p] !== typeof x[p]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (p in x) {
        if (y.hasOwnProperty(p) !== x.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (typeof y[p] !== typeof x[p]) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (typeof (x[p])) {
            case 'object':
            case 'function':

                leftChain.push(x);
                rightChain.push(y);

                if (!compare2Objects (x[p], y[p])) {
                    return false;
                }

                leftChain.pop();
                rightChain.pop();
                break;

            default:
                if (x[p] !== y[p]) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return true;
  }

  if (arguments.length < 1) {
    return true; //Die silently? Don't know how to handle such case, please help...
    // throw "Need two or more arguments to compare";
  }

  for (i = 1, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {

      leftChain = []; //Todo: this can be cached
      rightChain = [];

      if (!compare2Objects(arguments[0], arguments[i])) {
          return false;
      }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Known issues (well, they have very low priority, probably you'll never notice them):

- objects with different prototype structure but same projection
- functions may have identical text but refer to different closures

**Tests:** passes tests are from *[How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16788517/139361)*.

Comment: The check against `undefined` will fail for when a property is defined but set to the `undefined` value. Use the `in` operator instead of `typeof` to avoid this: `p in x`. Also comparing functions by string value is highly unreliable. Apart from the usual reasons that function decomposition fails, it's also very common to have two functions with the same code but very different behaviour due to closures. eg. any function created by jQuery's `$.proxy` or Prototype's `Function#bind`. I'd just stick with comparing function identity.

Comment: I think you should use *identical* comparison operator: `===`, cause `{ a: 5 }` and `{ a: "5.0" }` aren't equal, or are they?

Comment: If the object tree contains a loop, this will result in a stack overflow.

Comment: You shouldn't extend Object.prototype if it can be avoided. It causes ugly problems such as breaking `for(var key in someObject)` if there's no `if(!someObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;` inside that loop.

Comment: the function comparison is wrong: functions may have identical text but refer to different closures.  Better to just return `this[p] === x[p]`.

Comment: Regarding **1)** *"The ORDER of the properties IS IMPORTANT, so this method will return false for following objects:"* That's not necessarily true. That method ***may*** return `false` for those object, or it may not. There's no guarantee either way. That's why we don't use `JSON.stringify` comparison for Object comparison. There's no guarantees of order.

Comment: Smart way of comparing it with JSON.stringfy, of course with the catch of key:pair sequence matter.

Comment: your solution 1 works if you sort them first so the ordering is consistent. I prefer that over inserting that huge glob of javascript above.

Comment: Method 1 will not work for regex properties.

Answer (score 227):

Here is my **ES3** commented solution (gory details after the code):

```
function object_equals( x, y ) {
  if ( x === y ) return true;
    // if both x and y are null or undefined and exactly the same

  if ( ! ( x instanceof Object ) || ! ( y instanceof Object ) ) return false;
    // if they are not strictly equal, they both need to be Objects

  if ( x.constructor !== y.constructor ) return false;
    // they must have the exact same prototype chain, the closest we can do is
    // test there constructor.

  for ( var p in x ) {
    if ( ! x.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) continue;
      // other properties were tested using x.constructor === y.constructor

    if ( ! y.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) return false;
      // allows to compare x[ p ] and y[ p ] when set to undefined

    if ( x[ p ] === y[ p ] ) continue;
      // if they have the same strict value or identity then they are equal

    if ( typeof( x[ p ] ) !== "object" ) return false;
      // Numbers, Strings, Functions, Booleans must be strictly equal

    if ( ! object_equals( x[ p ],  y[ p ] ) ) return false;
      // Objects and Arrays must be tested recursively
  }

  for ( p in y )
    if ( y.hasOwnProperty( p ) && ! x.hasOwnProperty( p ) )
      return false;
        // allows x[ p ] to be set to undefined

  return true;
}
```

In developing this solution, I took a particular look at corner cases, efficiency, yet trying to yield a simple solution that works, hopefully with some elegance. JavaScript allows both ***null*** and ***undefined*** properties and objects have ***prototypes chains*** that can lead to very different behaviors if not checked.

First I have chosen to not extend ***Object.prototype***, mostly because ***null*** could not be one of the objects of the comparison and that I believe that ***null*** should be a valid object to compare with another. There are also other legitimate concerns noted by others regarding the extension of ***Object.prototype*** regarding possible side effects on other's code.

Special care must taken to deal the possibility that JavaScript allows object properties can be set to ***undefined***, i.e. there exists properties which values are set to ***undefined***. The above solution verifies that both objects have the same properties set to ***undefined*** to report equality. This can only be accomplished by checking the existence of properties using ***Object.hasOwnProperty( property_name )***. Also note that ***JSON.stringify()*** removes properties that are set to ***undefined***, and that therefore comparisons using this form will ignore properties set to the value ***undefined***.

Functions should be considered equal only if they share the same reference, not just the same code, because this would not take into account these functions prototype. So comparing the code string does not work to guaranty that they have the same prototype object.

The two objects should have the same ***prototype chain***, not just the same properties. This can only be tested cross-browser by comparing the ***constructor*** of both objects for strict equality. ECMAScript 5 would allow to test their actual prototype using ***Object.getPrototypeOf()***. Some web browsers also offer a **__proto__** property that does the same thing. A possible improvement of the above code would allow to use one of these methods whenever available.

The use of strict comparisons is paramount here because ***2*** should not be considered equal to ***"2.0000"***, nor ***false*** should be considered equal to ***null***, ***undefined***, or ***0***.

Efficiency considerations lead me to compare for equality of properties as soon as possible. Then, only if that failed, look for the ***typeof*** these properties. The speed boost could be significant on large objects with lots of scalar properties.

No more that two loops are required, the first to check properties from the left object, the second to check properties from the right and verify only existence (not value), to catch these properties which are defined with the ***undefined*** value.

Overall this code handles most corner cases in only 16 lines of code (without comments).

---

**Update (8/13/2015)**. I have implemented a better version, as the function [value_equals()](https://github.com/ReactiveSets/toubkal/blob/master/lib/util/value_equals.js) that is faster, handles properly corner cases such as NaN and 0 different than -0, optionally enforcing objects' properties order and testing for cyclic references, backed by more than [100 automated tests](https://github.com/ReactiveSets/toubkal/blob/master/test/src/value_equals.coffee) as part of the [Toubkal](https://github.com/ReactiveSets/toubkal) project test suite.

Answer (score 60):

```
  Utils.compareObjects = function(o1, o2){
    for(var p in o1){
        if(o1.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            if(o1[p] !== o2[p]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(var p in o2){
        if(o2.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            if(o1[p] !== o2[p]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Simple way to compare ONE-LEVEL only objects.

Comment: This isn't very efficient though, because if both objects are equal, each property will get compared twice.

Answer (score 22):

Certainly not the only way - you could prototype a method (against Object here but I certainly wouldn't suggest using Object for live code) to replicate C#/Java style comparison methods.

Edit, since a general example seems to be expected:

```
Object.prototype.equals = function(x)
{
    for(p in this)
    {
        switch(typeof(this[p]))
        {
            case 'object':
                if (!this[p].equals(x[p])) { return false }; break;
            case 'function':
                if (typeof(x[p])=='undefined' || (p != 'equals' && this[p].toString() != x[p].toString())) { return false; }; break;
            default:
                if (this[p] != x[p]) { return false; }
        }
    }

    for(p in x)
    {
        if(typeof(this[p])=='undefined') {return false;}
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note that testing methods with toString() is *absolutely not good enough* but a method which would be acceptable is very hard because of the problem of whitespace having meaning or not, never mind synonym methods and methods producing the same result with different implementations. *And* the problems of prototyping against Object in general.

Answer (score 21):

The following algorithm will deal with self-referential data structures, numbers, strings, dates, and of course plain nested javascript objects:

Objects are considered equivalent when

- They are exactly equal per `===` (String and Number are unwrapped first to ensure `42` is equivalent to `Number(42)`)
- or they are both dates and have the same `valueOf()`
- or they are both of the same type and not null and...

  - they are not objects and are equal per `==` (catches numbers/strings/booleans)
  - or, ignoring properties with `undefined` value they have the same properties all of which are considered recursively equivalent.

**Functions** are not considered identical by function text.  This test is insufficient because functions may have differing closures.  Functions are only considered equal if `===` says so (but you could easily extend that equivalent relation should you choose to do so).

**Infinite loops**, potentially caused by circular datastructures, are avoided.  When `areEquivalent` attempts to disprove equality and recurses into an object's properties to do so, it keeps track of the objects for which this sub-comparison is needed.  If equality can be disproved, then some reachable property path differs between the objects, and then there must be a shortest such reachable path, and that shortest reachable path cannot contain cycles present in both paths; i.e. it is OK to assume equality when recursively comparing objects.  The assumption is stored in a property `areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34`, which is deleted after use, but if the object graph already contains such a property, behavior is undefined.  The use of such a marker property is necessary because javascript doesn't support dictionaries using arbitrary objects as keys.

```
function unwrapStringOrNumber(obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Number || obj instanceof String 
            ? obj.valueOf() 
            : obj);
}
function areEquivalent(a, b) {
    a = unwrapStringOrNumber(a);
    b = unwrapStringOrNumber(b);
    if (a === b) return true; //e.g. a and b both null
    if (a === null || b === null || typeof (a) !== typeof (b)) return false;
    if (a instanceof Date) 
        return b instanceof Date && a.valueOf() === b.valueOf();
    if (typeof (a) !== "object") 
        return a == b; //for boolean, number, string, xml

    var newA = (a.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34 === undefined),
        newB = (b.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34 === undefined);
    try {
        if (newA) a.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34 = [];
        else if (a.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34.some(
            function (other) { return other === b; })) return true;
        if (newB) b.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34 = [];
        else if (b.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34.some(
            function (other) { return other === a; })) return true;
        a.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34.push(b);
        b.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34.push(a);

        var tmp = {};
        for (var prop in a) 
            if(prop != "areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34") 
                tmp[prop] = null;
        for (var prop in b) 
            if (prop != "areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34") 
                tmp[prop] = null;

        for (var prop in tmp) 
            if (!areEquivalent(a[prop], b[prop]))
                return false;
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (newA) delete a.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34;
        if (newB) delete b.areEquivalent_Eq_91_2_34;
    }
}
```

Comment: still working for complex nested objects, thank you

Answer (score 17):

I wrote this piece of code for object comparison, and it seems to work. check the assertions:

```
function countProps(obj) {
    var count = 0;
    for (k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
};

function objectEquals(v1, v2) {

    if (typeof(v1) !== typeof(v2)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof(v1) === "function") {
        return v1.toString() === v2.toString();
    }

    if (v1 instanceof Object && v2 instanceof Object) {
        if (countProps(v1) !== countProps(v2)) {
            return false;
        }
        var r = true;
        for (k in v1) {
            r = objectEquals(v1[k], v2[k]);
            if (!r) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return v1 === v2;
    }
}

assert.isTrue(objectEquals(null,null));
assert.isFalse(objectEquals(null,undefined));

assert.isTrue(objectEquals("hi","hi"));
assert.isTrue(objectEquals(5,5));
assert.isFalse(objectEquals(5,10));

assert.isTrue(objectEquals([],[]));
assert.isTrue(objectEquals([1,2],[1,2]));
assert.isFalse(objectEquals([1,2],[2,1]));
assert.isFalse(objectEquals([1,2],[1,2,3]));

assert.isTrue(objectEquals({},{}));
assert.isTrue(objectEquals({a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:2}));
assert.isTrue(objectEquals({a:1,b:2},{b:2,a:1}));
assert.isFalse(objectEquals({a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:3}));

assert.isTrue(objectEquals({1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:26}},{1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:26}}));
assert.isFalse(objectEquals({1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:26}},{1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:27}}));

assert.isTrue(objectEquals(function(x){return x;},function(x){return x;}));
assert.isFalse(objectEquals(function(x){return x;},function(y){return y+2;}));
```

Comment: Put let befor k in for loop causing error

Answer (score 6):

I have modified a bit the code above. for me *0 !== false* and *null !== undefined*. If you do not need such strict check remove one "*=*" sign in "*this[p] !== x[p]*" inside the code.

```
Object.prototype.equals = function(x){
    for (var p in this) {
        if(typeof(this[p]) !== typeof(x[p])) return false;
        if((this[p]===null) !== (x[p]===null)) return false;
        switch (typeof(this[p])) {
            case 'undefined':
                if (typeof(x[p]) != 'undefined') return false;
                break;
            case 'object':
                if(this[p]!==null && x[p]!==null && (this[p].constructor.toString() !== x[p].constructor.toString() || !this[p].equals(x[p]))) return false;
                break;
            case 'function':
                if (p != 'equals' && this[p].toString() != x[p].toString()) return false;
                break;
            default:
                if (this[p] !== x[p]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then I have tested it with next objects:

```
var a = {a: 'text', b:[0,1]};
var b = {a: 'text', b:[0,1]};
var c = {a: 'text', b: 0};
var d = {a: 'text', b: false};
var e = {a: 'text', b:[1,0]};
var f = {a: 'text', b:[1,0], f: function(){ this.f = this.b; }};
var g = {a: 'text', b:[1,0], f: function(){ this.f = this.b; }};
var h = {a: 'text', b:[1,0], f: function(){ this.a = this.b; }};
var i = {
    a: 'text',
    c: {
        b: [1, 0],
        f: function(){
            this.a = this.b;
        }
    }
};
var j = {
    a: 'text',
    c: {
        b: [1, 0],
        f: function(){
            this.a = this.b;
        }
    }
};
var k = {a: 'text', b: null};
var l = {a: 'text', b: undefined};
```

a==b expected true; returned true

a==c expected false; returned false

c==d expected false; returned false

a==e expected false; returned false

f==g expected true; returned true

h==g expected false; returned false

i==j expected true; returned true

d==k expected false; returned false

k==l expected false; returned false

Comment: +1 for testing the constructor or sub objects. But why not testing that of the main object? And why not testing functions by reference instead of comparing strings using toString(), this is slow and unaccurate.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version, pretty much stuff from this thread is integrated (same counts for the test cases):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "equals", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function (obj) {
        var p;
        if (this === obj) {
            return true;
        }

        // some checks for native types first

        // function and sring
        if (typeof(this) === "function" || typeof(this) === "string" || this instanceof String) { 
            return this.toString() === obj.toString();
        }

        // number
        if (this instanceof Number || typeof(this) === "number") {
            if (obj instanceof Number || typeof(obj) === "number") {
                return this.valueOf() === obj.valueOf();
            }
            return false;
        }

        // null.equals(null) and undefined.equals(undefined) do not inherit from the 
        // Object.prototype so we can return false when they are passed as obj
        if (typeof(this) !== typeof(obj) || obj === null || typeof(obj) === "undefined") {
            return false;
        }

        function sort (o) {
            var result = {};

            if (typeof o !== "object") {
                return o;
            }

            Object.keys(o).sort().forEach(function (key) {
                result[key] = sort(o[key]);
            });

            return result;
        }

        if (typeof(this) === "object") {
            if (Array.isArray(this)) { // check on arrays
                return JSON.stringify(this) === JSON.stringify(obj);                
            } else { // anyway objects
                for (p in this) {
                    if (typeof(this[p]) !== typeof(obj[p])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if ((this[p] === null) !== (obj[p] === null)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    switch (typeof(this[p])) {
                    case 'undefined':
                        if (typeof(obj[p]) !== 'undefined') {
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'object':
                        if (this[p] !== null 
                                && obj[p] !== null 
                                && (this[p].constructor.toString() !== obj[p].constructor.toString() 
                                        || !this[p].equals(obj[p]))) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'function':
                        if (this[p].toString() !== obj[p].toString()) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (this[p] !== obj[p]) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                };

            }
        }

        // at least check them with JSON
        return JSON.stringify(sort(this)) === JSON.stringify(sort(obj));
    }
});
```

Here is my TestCase:

```
    assertFalse({}.equals(null));
    assertFalse({}.equals(undefined));

    assertTrue("String", "hi".equals("hi"));
    assertTrue("Number", new Number(5).equals(5));
    assertFalse("Number", new Number(5).equals(10));
    assertFalse("Number+String", new Number(1).equals("1"));

    assertTrue([].equals([]));
    assertTrue([1,2].equals([1,2]));
    assertFalse([1,2].equals([2,1]));
    assertFalse([1,2].equals([1,2,3]));

    assertTrue(new Date("2011-03-31").equals(new Date("2011-03-31")));
    assertFalse(new Date("2011-03-31").equals(new Date("1970-01-01")));

    assertTrue({}.equals({}));
    assertTrue({a:1,b:2}.equals({a:1,b:2}));
    assertTrue({a:1,b:2}.equals({b:2,a:1}));
    assertFalse({a:1,b:2}.equals({a:1,b:3}));

    assertTrue({1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:26}}.equals({1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:26}}));
    assertFalse({1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:26}}.equals({1:{name:"mhc",age:28}, 2:{name:"arb",age:27}}));

    assertTrue("Function", (function(x){return x;}).equals(function(x){return x;}));
    assertFalse("Function", (function(x){return x;}).equals(function(y){return y+2;}));

    var a = {a: 'text', b:[0,1]};
    var b = {a: 'text', b:[0,1]};
    var c = {a: 'text', b: 0};
    var d = {a: 'text', b: false};
    var e = {a: 'text', b:[1,0]};
    var f = {a: 'text', b:[1,0], f: function(){ this.f = this.b; }};
    var g = {a: 'text', b:[1,0], f: function(){ this.f = this.b; }};
    var h = {a: 'text', b:[1,0], f: function(){ this.a = this.b; }};
    var i = {
        a: 'text',
        c: {
            b: [1, 0],
            f: function(){
                this.a = this.b;
            }
        }
    };
    var j = {
        a: 'text',
        c: {
            b: [1, 0],
            f: function(){
                this.a = this.b;
            }
        }
    };
    var k = {a: 'text', b: null};
    var l = {a: 'text', b: undefined};

    assertTrue(a.equals(b));
    assertFalse(a.equals(c));
    assertFalse(c.equals(d));
    assertFalse(a.equals(e));
    assertTrue(f.equals(g));
    assertFalse(h.equals(g));
    assertTrue(i.equals(j));
    assertFalse(d.equals(k));
    assertFalse(k.equals(l));
```

Comment: JSON.stringify() removes properties that are set to undefined, and that therefore comparisons using this form will ignore properties set to the value undefined: assertFalse([1,2,null].equals([1,2,undefined])).

Comment: You are stringifying arrays, but array can have complex objects inside

Comment: Shouldn't this test assert false instead of true because one is an instance of Object and the other is a primative? assertTrue("Number", new Number(5).equals(5));

Answer (score 3):

If you work without the JSON library, maybe this will help you out:

```
Object.prototype.equals = function(b) {
    var a = this;
    for(i in a) {
        if(typeof b[i] == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
        if(typeof b[i] == 'object') {
            if(!b[i].equals(a[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(b[i] != a[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(i in b) {
        if(typeof a[i] == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
        if(typeof a[i] == 'object') {
            if(!a[i].equals(b[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(a[i] != b[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var a = {foo:'bar', bar: {blub:'bla'}};
var b = {foo:'bar', bar: {blub:'blob'}};
alert(a.equals(b)); // alert's a false
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Modifying Object.prototype can have all sort of unforeseen consequences.

Comment: You cannot work without the JSON library, it is part of the Javascript standard library: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check for methods explicitly you can use the method.toSource() or method.toString() methods.

Comment: really not good enough for the reasons I described

Comment: So you'd spin through the elements of the object, and check what the types are, then use toSource() or toString() when you find a function?

Comment: Nosredna, yes. That would give you the actual text of the function.

annakata, I don't understand what's not good enough and what you are actually trying to do. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @snz3 - there's a serious problem with whitespace, dropped semi-colons and braces and similar syntax differences which may or may not have an impact, and are hard to determine without parsing i.e. decoupling from a raw string format. There's also the problem of fluctuating state and prototyping. Basically strings are not good enough at capturing the state of two objects.

Comment: Hello from 2021, `toSource` is deprecated, don't use it